# WP keeps looking up post thumbnail on https even though wp-config says http

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, wp-config

In wp-config.php I set:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://cdn.example.com/wp');
```

but WP's `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` keeps looking up static content on https://cdn.example.com. In the admin, it's all good, using http. In post content, all good, http. However, function `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` keeps returning https which is obviously wrong, so the image doesn't show up.

I almost think there is no way around it, other than manually getting the picture or writing my own function to do that for me.

But I still have a bit of hope that someone might help here.

Comment: Did you try a search/replace on the database?